# Check how old a process is on Linux

Tags: process

I just set a sleep program to run for two hours, and I want to know how to see how old it is because I forgot exactly when I started it. Is there a file in `/proc` with this information or a command that says so? (of course this code won't have 100% cpu power or any significant amount at all.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about /proc, but the following will give you this info:

```
ps -eo pid,cmd,etime
```

Example output:

```
30483 [kworker/u17:2]                03:48:02
30628 /usr/bin/dirmngr --supervis  8-09:37:37
31753 /usr/lib/firefox/firefox -c    03:34:37
32239 xfce4-volumed                1-22:11:11
32245 xfce4-power-manager          1-22:11:10
```

Where the 8- and 1- are days elapsed.

The above ps command specifies 3 fields to be included in the output: the process pid, the command, and the elapsed time, respectively.

etime is the elapsed time since the process was started, in the form dd-hh:mm:ss. dd is the number of days; hh, the number of hours; mm, the number of minutes; ss, the number of seconds.

If you want to know this for a specific process, like for example the process with id 100:

```
ps -q 100 -eo etime
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please accept the answer? That way it will be clear for everyone that this works.